# $G$ nilpotent group and $N\trianglelefteq G$ then $[N,G]<N$, attempt of the proof

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

I need help in proving this fact:

Let be $G$  nilpotent group and $N$ a normal and non trivial subgroup. Then $[N,G]$ is a proper subgroup of $N$.

My attempt:

I know the following fact:
Let be $H$ a subgroup of $G$ and $N$ normal in $G$.
$[H,G]<N$ if and only if $HN/N\subset Z(G/N)$

I don't know how to use this fact. Should I consider the central series of $N$?

Can someone help me? thank you!

Comment: No need of nilpotency: $\;N\lhd G\iff [G,N]\le N\;$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $[N,G]$ is not proper in $N$, then according to the fact you give, if you take $H=N$, we have $N/N\not\subset Z(G/N)$ which implies $Z(G/N)=1$. But since $G$ is nilpotent, so is $G/N$. Therefore $Z(G/N)$ cannot be trivial, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

That much is true for **any** normal subgroup of **any** group, not *only* nilpotent ones: for any group $\;G\;$ and $\;N\le G\;$ , we have that

$$N\lhd G\iff [N,G]\le N$$

I'll give you some hints about one direction, you try the rest by yourself:

$$[G,N]\le N\implies \;\forall\,n\in N\;\forall\,x\in G,\;\; N\ni x^{-1}n^{-1}xn\implies$$

$$\left(x^{-1}n^{-1}x\right)n=n'\in N\implies x^{-1}n^{-1}x=n'n^{-1}\in N\;\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to prove that $[N,G]$ is a proper subgroup of $N$